# Getting an attribute value in xml generated from UML models

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have an xml string like this and I want to get attribute value of "Element/xmi:type/name". It means I want to retreive name of element of type- activity only in a loop for each element. How do I do that? I am using javax.xml.parsers library.

```
    <element xmi:idref="EAID_53685791_7F62_48a2_8BE8_DB7513AC776A" xmi:type="uml:Activity" name="Return error value" scope="public">
            <model package="EAPK_263A2FE8_8346_4d1e_A851_39B9D573143D" tpos="0" ea_localid="98" ea_eleType="element"/>
            <properties isSpecification="false" sType="Activity" nType="0" scope="public" isAbstract="false"/>
            <project author="shiva999" version="1.0" phase="1.0" created="2016-08-16 09:44:25" modified="2016-08-16 10:13:51" complexity="1" status="Proposed"/>
            <code gentype="&lt;none&gt;"/>
            <style appearance="BackColor=-1;BorderColor=-1;BorderWidth=-1;FontColor=-1;VSwimLanes=1;HSwimLanes=1;BorderStyle=0;"/>
            <modelDocument/>
            <tags/>
            <xrefs/>
            <extendedProperties tagged="0" package_name="Activity Model"/>
            <links>
                <ControlFlow xmi:id="EAID_873CF8C4_0192_4099_8F66_6B36FA760AB6" start="EAID_53685791_7F62_48a2_8BE8_DB7513AC776A" end="EAID_D2EB427B_3AFD_4700_BD72_13B36684E595"/>
                <ControlFlow xmi:id="EAID_2FECE2AE_6CA0_48a4_82AE_D743D257F37C" start="EAID_0D85B784_4393_429e_9BA1_7983BD7891CA" end="EAID_53685791_7F62_48a2_8BE8_DB7513AC776A"/>
            </links>
        </element>
```

Below is the code which I have written. Getting error as "The method type(int) is undefined for the type NodeLis". I am new to xml parsing and is refering online tutorials

```
    public class DomXMLParser {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(new File("activity.xml"));
    NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("Type");
    for(int x=0,size= nodeList.getLength(); x<size; x++) {
        System.out.println(nodeList.type(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi,
I would use XPath: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html
The support is native, it's just a matter of setting up a reader and passing it the right path.

Comment: @BugProtectionActivist I have posted the xpath which I used. No expected output. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code used using XPath. Not getting the expected result. I have many such activity nodes and transition edges for those. So I need to store them as a list and create a hierarchial graph.

```
    public class DomXMLParser {
public static void main(String[] args)  throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, 
IOException, XPathExpressionException {
//DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
try {
    File fXmlFile = new File("C:/Projekte/activity.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression expr 
     = xpath.compile("//xmi:XMI[xmi:type ='uml:Activity']/name/text()");
   Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I need a complete XML (with the headers) to test it but I believe the correct xpath would look like `//element[@xmi:type='uml:Activity']/name/text()`